# Anonymous class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Getting some trouble to do the following in typescript. I've the following interface defined :

```
 interface RendererCallback {

        getNode():HTMLElement;

        getTable();
 }
```

There is a method expecting a RenderCallback object like :

```
render( callback:RendererCallback )
```

How do I create an anonymous instance in the middle of my code :

```
myObject.render( new .. {
  getNode() {
    return myNode;
  }
  getTable() {
    .. some code...
    return something;
  }
 } );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use anonymous objects and lambdas:

```
myObject.render({
    getNode: () => { doSomething...; return myNode },
    getTable: () => myTable
});
```

Note, the `new` keyword is not used.

Comment: You beat me to it, but yes, those actually are functions in my original answer. The `return` statement is implicit for single-expression lambdas without brackets. It's equivalent to this in vanilla JavaScript: `getNode: function() { return myNode; }`

Answer (score 6):

Typescript now supports class expressions so you can make actual anonymous classes.

```
myObject.render( new class {
  getNode() {
    return myNode;
  }
  getTable() {
    .. some code...
    return something;
  }
 } );
```

This has the benefit of `this` not being inferred to be `any` within the anonymous class' methods.

Comment: The full syntax for typed anonymous classes is `new class implements MyInterface` or `new class extends MyClass { } (constructorArgs)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a full code sample that works:

```
 interface RendererCallback {

        getNode():HTMLElement;

        getTable();
 }

 class thing {
     render(callback: RendererCallback) {

     }
 }

 var myObject = new thing();

 myObject.render(  {
    getNode() {
        return null;
    },

    getTable() {

    }


    } 
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it to nice to declare it like this:

```
propertyName: RendererCallback = {
  getNode: () => myNode, // no braces needed to only return something
  getTable() => {
    .. some code...
    return something;
  }
};
```